# Unable to make Http Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

I am trying to access data from BitcoinAverage using their API. I am following a tutorial and I should be getting a JSON file console-logged in the terminal but in my case it shows undefined(as you can see in the picture)[

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
    url = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD";
    request(url,function(error,response,body){
        console.log(body);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running at port 3000");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bitcoin Ticker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bitcoin Ticker</h1>

    <form action="/" method="post">
    <select name="crypto" id="">
        <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="ETH">Ethereum</option>
        <option value="LTC">Litecoin</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fiat" id="">
        <option value="USD">Bitcoin</option>
        <option value="GBP">Ethereum</option>
        <option value="EUR">Litecoin</option>
    </select>
    
    <button type="submit" name="button">Check</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Nodejs Output]

Comment: It works fine when I test it.

Comment: **Danger**: [The request module has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: Is it possible you are getting an error? Have you tried `console.error(error)`?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. There's not enough information here to help.

Comment: erics2783 It shows: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com'

Comment: It was probably a network problem. I dont know how but since I am on a new network it is working. Thanks anyways!